# AppStore GEO restrict app to specific USA states

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, geofencing

I want to publish an `iOS` application which should be available in specific USA states only. What I have found till now is how to specify territory or country on `iTunesConnect`, but I didn't find how to select some states to be available in them only.

**Is this doable on `iTunesConnect`? or even through the app itself?**

Also I have found that it is possible to use Geofencing to determine some regions which the code can monitor user's location to detect entering/exiting to/from them.

**Is there an easy way to detect this info only once - may be while installing the app or even when the app is first launched - without need to seep track of user's location?**

Comment: In itunes connect there is an option for selecting-deselecting country for your app. Just deselect only USA & select other in restricted. I would like to post screen shot but currently I don't have iTunes access.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I have tried this, but this allows me to select the whole country. In case of USA, I would like to allow app installation and usage in specific states only.

Comment: yes, that's correct. You can only select country not any specific region or state of a country. As per my knowledge, I am afraid that Apple would not allow this if you are going to use some custom code(Which is possible) within the app. You can only restrict country App store.

Comment: but it is Apple who required to add Geo restriction for my app for specific states only - in which using this app will be legal - !!!

Comment: I am unable to answer as per my knowledge Apple would not allow this. Moreover we can't control iTunes for any specific state/region. If we are going to add location based code in the app then in that case app would not work outside on selected region but it does not restrict the user(Who does not belong to specific region/state) to download the app.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to restrict to only certain states?

Comment: I am having the same issue. any progress on this?

Comment: The solution I could implement is to use each state's longitude and latitude to determine geofencing areas. The problem is that geofencing areas are limited to 20 only and the states I was trying to restrict was 29. So, I made a workaround by gathering each two or three adjacent states in one area. It worked with me but it needs some accurate calculations to avoid errors.

Comment: I got the same issue. @AmaniElsaed is right, you need to Monitor Geographical Regions (limited to 20), and check if the user is inside (using "requestStateForRegion") and later be notified if the user changes region ("didEnterRegion", "didExitRegion"). All Core Locations methods.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1